# How to use MathJax and LaTeX in JavaScript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, latex, mathjax

I'm working on a coding project that needs to display math based on human input. I'm hoping to have code that live updates the user's text with LaTeX. For example, the user types `1/2` and it is replaced with `\frac{1}{2}`, then is accurately displayed on the document.

What I'm currently stuck on is getting LaTeX to work with JavaScript and HTML. I've looked at MathJax, but I'm not sure how to use it to dynamically update text to display LaTeX.